# Unable to clone Azure repo to the Build Agent server/pool

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm unable to clone my Azure devOps repo inside my Build Agent server/pool.
However, cloning using Github repo works fine.

Error:
"fatal: could not read username for 'https://devops.azure.com': Terminal prompts disabled"

Generated PAT in ADO, and run git clone https://PAT@dev.azure.com/Org

and

Enabled "Allow script to access the Oauth Token"

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can consider adding config parameters in the git clone command:

For example:

Windows:

```
$MyPat = 'yourPAT'

$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$MyPat"))

git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

Linux:

```
MY_PAT=yourPAT # replace "yourPAT" with "PatStringFromWebUI"
B64_PAT=$(printf ":%s" "$MY_PAT" | base64)
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

On the other hand, if you are using the **system.accesstoken** variable for authentication, you can try to use the following commnad:

```
git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```